# Place holders in Yesod subsite

Tags: haskell, yesod

Say I have a subsite `Profile` which can display the profile of an user (with his website, the name of his dog and all those matters), and another subsite `Social` which manage friendship between users.

I would like that on the profile page of Michael, I can click on "become friend with Michael" (because he builds wonderful framework ;) ).  With respect to encapsulation, I can neither put this piece of code in `Profile` nor in `Social`. So I thought about word press and the ability we have to put placeholders in themes where we can put any widget we want.

This led me to the following:

```
instance  YesodProfile App where
        <random stuff>
        placeholder userId = [ becomeFriendWidget userId, likeThisGuyWidget userId]
```

Then the `Profile` subsite has to display somewhere in the profile page the given widgets.

Does it look to be a good solution? Does it exist another "standard" solution of this kind of issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like a pretty good solution to me. It's not so terribly different from how yesod-auth does its plugin capabilities, so there's certain some level of prior art.